# Custom HTTP Request from iOS is rejected

Tags: ios, swift, http

I am trying to send an HTTP request to a php script on iOS. I use multipart/form-data because I also need to be able to send JPEGs. The user agent is curl sending a request from curl in terminal works every time. Here is the request I end up generating from the code I have below.

```
POST /Folder/GetData.php HTTP/1.1
Host: website_goes_here
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=This12@
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Length: 146
Accept: */*
User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive


--This12@
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uname

ThisIsTheUserNameHere
--This12@
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=pass

PasswordGoesHere
--This12@--
```

Here is the swift code I use to generate this request (data is a variable sent to the function with an array of dictionaries.):

```
var request=NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: “website-HERE”)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
request.timeoutInterval=NSTimeInterval(60)
request.HTTPMethod="POST";
var end="This12@";

request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary="+end, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("*/*" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("close" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
request.setValue("100-continue", forHTTPHeaderField: "Expect")
request.setValue("curl/7.37.1", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
var body=NSMutableData()

body.appendData(("\r\n--"+end+"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
var first=true
for object in data{
    if !(first){
        body.appendData(("\r\n--"+end+"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    }
    first=false
    if((object[“Content-Type”] as! String)=="text/plain"){
    body.appendData(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="+(object[“name”] as! String)+"\r\n\r\n"+(object[“TextToSend”] as! String)).dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    }else{
        var part1="Content-Disposition: attatchment; name="+(object[“name”] as! String)
        var part2="; filename="+(object[“FileName”] as! String)+";\r\nContent-Type: "
        body.appendData((part1+part2+(object[“Content-Type”] as! String)+"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
        body.appendData(object[“Data”] as! NSData);

    }



}
body.appendData(("\r\n--"+end+"--\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
request.HTTPBody=body
```

What happens is my GoDaddy website returns a valid response for the first few times and then the connection starts getting reset for the next minute and this repeats. Is there any reason for this? Please respond with either corrections for the code or the HTTP request. If this helps, the connection is sent with:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) ->
        Void in
println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding));
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that GoDaddy has a post limit per ip in a certain amount of time. Shared Hosting plans have a limit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your code for actually sending the request and handling the response.

My guess though is that you're not reading to the end of the response, and so the connection is not being closed.  That will leave you with lots of connections held open, until GoDaddy decides to throttle you.

Comment: How would I be able to close the connection? I added my code to the question.

Comment: I think `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` does it for you.  So much for that theory.  I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I found out what the problem was below.